# Google Maps directions API waypoints optimize

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am having issue with Google Maps API:
When I am requesting following url it returns results
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens

But using waypoints=optimize:true returns no data
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&waypoints=optimize:true

I can't understand the reason. Please some one help.

I have checked the doc they said to put waypoints between, but what if origin and destination is dynamic and I don't know the waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't get any results, because you don't actually pass any waypoints. This is the example request provided in the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA
```

Try adding some waypoints by appending it to your request and separating them by using the pipe character `|`.

Comment: But what if the origin and destination are dynamic?What If I don't know the waypoints?

Comment: You'll have to know your waypoints at one point, otherwise there's no way or reason in using waypoints. Once you know your waypoints, you can generate your request url dynamically.